# Decode Garmin rsd sonar binary data in R

Tags: r

I've been working with a garmin chartplotter lately, but all of the data requires an ios app to even look at. I'm interested in taking the sonar/sounder data and pulling it into a csv to simply extract depth by time (so I can merge it with the data from the gpx file for a depth track).

Anyone have any experience or suggestions for doing so?

```
to.read <- file("TestSonar.RSD", "rb")
a <- readBin(to.read, 
             raw(), 
             n = file.size("TestSonar.RSD"),
              endian = "little", signed = FALSE)
close(to.read)
```

produces a nice full bit of hex.......not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Have you tried examining the resulting file in CyberChef or similar? We don't have the data, so it's impossible for us to provide additional assistance.

Comment: Here is a link https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmdc8qml3he5e5p/TestSonar.RSD?dl=0